# shadow DOM not showing content. How to make content visible in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shadow-dom

As you can see I want to add content dynamically but shadow DOM is not showing content How can I make content visible? I want to make content visible.

```js
let shadow = document.querySelector('#nameTag').createShadowRoot();
let content_area =  document.querySelector("#nameTag");
content_area.innerHTML = '<p>Hello world!</p>';
let template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
shadow.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode(true) );
shadow.appendChild( template.content );
```

```css
h2{
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
<div id="nameTag"></div>
<template id="nameTagTemplate">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="name"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not showing' ? The Shadow DOM isn't _meant_ to be visible...

Comment: I mean I want to make content visible.

Comment: You have no content beyond 'Hello World.' All elements are empty and you've provided no CSS styles. It's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

First you should be using the V1 function `attachShadow` instead of the V0 function `createShadowRoot`. The V0 spec is deprecated and will not be supported in most browsers and will be removed from Chrome soon.

Second, you need a `<slot>` in your template into which the children of `<div id="nameTag"></div>` will show.

Third you were appending both a clone of the template and the original template into the shadowRoot. Not sure you wanted to do that so I took it out in my example.

```js
let shadow = document.querySelector('#nameTag').attachShadow({mode:'open'});

let content_area =  document.querySelector("#nameTag");
content_area.innerHTML = 'I show in the slot';

let template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
shadow.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode(true) );
```

```css
h2{
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#nameTag {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
<div id="nameTag"></div>
<template id="nameTagTemplate">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="name"><slot></slot></div>
    </div>
</template>
```